# What is the difference between List(8,9).:::(List(1,2)) and List(1,2):::List(8,9) in scala?

Tags: scala

why we apply round braces while using dot operator and why  the output of

```
List(8,9).:::(List(1,2))
```

and      `List(1,2):::List(8,9)` same

Comment: Where do you see curly braces?

Comment: @Chris with the addition of dot why braces are needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is somewhat unclear, but I'm *guessing* your actual question is:

> how come:
>
> `List(1, 2) ::: List(3, 4) == 
>    List(3, 4).:::(List(1, 2)) ==
>    List(1, 2, 3, 4)`?

In other words, how come omitting the dot and the parenthesis also **reverses** the order of the arguments?

The answer is Scala's special *associativity* rules for **Infix Operators**, from the [Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), chapter 6.12.3:

> The associativity of an operator is determined by the operator’s last character. Operators
>   ending in a colon ‘:’ are right-associative. All other operators are left-associative.

This means that when infix notation is used (i.e. *without* the dot and parens), this operator (`:::`), which ends with a colon, uses the left-hand value as the method *argument* and the right-hand one as the object for which the method `:::` is called. When called as a regular method call (i.e with the dot and parens), the method is left-associative, as all methods are (the "left" object is the one on which it was called, the right one is the argument).

Comment: @Zohar Thanks this helped

Answer (score 2):

The "normal" Java-style way to invoke a method is `a.b(c)`. Scala offers an additional, equivalent notation for methods that have a single argument: you can omit both the dot and the parens to write `a b c`.

For methods with names ending in `:`, there is one additional rule: the method is invoked on the right operand instead of the left. So `a b: c` desugars to `c.b:(a)` instead of `a.b:(c)`.

Comment: Thanks @Chris and  Zohar both answers solved my problem and yes my question was little bit unclear , let me correct it